# PayPal not sending IPN

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I've set my IPN URL (and is active) in the PayPal account configuration and also in the PaymentDetailsType class:

```
$paymentDetails->NotifyURL = '[...]/IPN/IPNListener.php';
```

It doesn't seem to do anything when a transaction is completed, neither in sandbox or live env.

I've tested the listener with the IPN Simulator and works fine.

Any ideas? Should I reach PayPal?

Regards,

Comment: Are you using the SDK? or No?

Comment: Did you check IPN History in the PayPal account?  Did you check your web server logs?  If the IPNs actually are not being sent then you must not have it configured correctly.  If it is configured correctly, but you're not seeing happen when you expect to see happen, then there's probably an error happening within it which you could see from the logs.

Comment: @PP_MSI_Caleb Yes I am